# Use of $writememh in for loop

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

Can we use `$writememh` in a `for` loop? I am trying to write to a file from different memories alternatively, and I am getting a warning:

> Warning: More indices than needed

I have googled, but nothing is written about this warning. Below is the sample code:

```
reg [7:0] Mem_x[1023:0];
reg [7:0] Mem_y[1023:0];
reg [7:0] Mem_z[1023:0];
reg [31:0] image[1023:0];

initial
begin

#1000
for (l = 0; l < 25; l = l + 1)  
    
    @(posedge Clock)
     begin 
        $writememh("writefile_out.hex",Mem_x[l]);  
        $writememh("writefile_out.hex",Mem_y[l]); 
        $writememh("writefile_out.hex",Mem_z[l]);
        $writememh("writefile_out.hex",image[l][7:0]); 
     end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `Mem_x`, `Mem_y`, `Mem_z` and `image` are declared something like:

```
integer Mem_x[0:24];
integer Mem_y[0:24];
integer Mem_z[0:24];
reg [7:0] image[0:24];
```

In which case you want a file that reads something like:

```
{Mem_x[0]}
{Mem_y[0]}
{Mem_z[0]}
{image[0]}
{Mem_x[1]}
{Mem_y[1]}
{Mem_z[1]}
{image[1]}
{Mem_x[2]}
...
```

Where each of those in a hex value for the variable indicated.

If so, you cannot use `$writememh` to achieve this; because `$writememh` overwrites the given file, it does NOT append to it. So, with each call, you are erasing the previous contents of "writefile_out.hex". Also, the reason you are getting that error is because `Mem_x[l]` and the others are not arrays, they are elements of arrays and `$writememh` expects an array as an argument (thus, too many indexes error).

However, you can use `$fdisplay` to achieve what you want (and then some). Heres an example:

```
integer outfile;
integer i;
reg [7:0] mem1[0:9];
reg [7:0] mem2[0:9];

initial begin
  outfile = $fopen("out.hex");
  ...
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1) begin
    $fdisplay(outfile, "%02x\n%02x\n", mem1[i], mem2[i]);
  end
  ...
end
```

Using `$fdisplay` means you can format the output however you like, so it doesnt have to be constrained to the standard hex format used by `$readmemh` and `$writememh`, unless you want it to be, then you just use something like I have above.